# How to get Complement function working in a For loop?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

I've been working on a piece of code that will delete small components from a nested uneven matrix (n pages, n rows, 3 columns), by deleting the pages with less than ~30 rows.

However, I've notice that the `Complement` function doesn't seem to work in a For loop. The variable I assign to Complement gives a tag times error. If I put it outside a `For` loop, it works fine. For example, if you see the following code:

```
R = Range[10]

For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++
    K = Complement[R, {i, i + 1}]
    Print[K]]
```

It should output

`{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

`{1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

`{1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`..etc

But instead it gives:

> `Tag Times in 1 P is Protected.`

Is there an alternative to `Complement` that allows me to delete whatever pages I want?

Comment: `K` is a builtin symbol, which is unfortunately not `Protected`.  Assigning to `K` could easily cause Mathematica to return wrong symbolic results in certain rare cases.  BTW the reason why it fails is that many commas are missing

Comment: Szabolcs is referring to missing commas after i++ and before the Print function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html?q=For) syntax is just wrong. Try

```
r = Range[10]

For[i = 1, i <= 9, i++, k = Complement[r, {i, i + 1}]; Print[k]]
```

and avoid capital letters for your symbol names. `K` has a build-in meaning

```
Information[K]
```

> K is a default generic name for a summation index in a symbolic sum.

Answer (score 1):

A For-loop is a poor choice for your calculation in *Mathematica*. Better, because it's simpler and faster, is

```
sets = Table[Complement[Range[10], {i, i + 1}], {i, 9}];
```

which has the additional advantage that the results are available for further calculations. To get the results printed out nicely, use `Column`

```
Column @ sets
```

[image: sets]